# How many solutions does a linear system with 4 equations and 3 with associated matrix M=(A/B) such that DET(M)≠0

Tags: linear-algebra

let S be a linear system of 4 equations and 3 variables, and let M=(A|B) be the complete matrix associated to S.

If **det(M)≠0**, which one of the following statements is certainly true?

(a) S admits only one solution.

(b) S admits ∞^1 solutions.

(c) S admits ∞^2 solutions.

(d) The null vector is not a solution of S

The solution is (d).I got this from some practice quizzes i have for linear algebra in my university portal! I have an exam in 3 days and if you can help me understand the thought process behind this i would be grateful!

There were some other variations of this problem where Det(M)=0 and if so which of these answers mentioned above would be correct in this case! But First of all i can't understand how the associated matrix of a system of linear equations with **4 equations and 3 variables** can have a Det! I thought that only square matrixes can have a Det!

Comment: The fourth column of $M$ is your augmented part, which makes $M$ a $4 \times 4$ matrix. If the null vector were a solution to $S$ then the fourth column of $M$ would have to be all zeroes. Is this possible?

Comment: @Matthew I am so embarassed right now for not noticing that earlier! Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: No problem. Do you know if this system of equations is consistent?

Comment: @Matthew but w8 a minute! I think he is speaking generally here! I know that a Linear system of equations can be written as Ax=B and i know depending on the det of A you can get an idea of how many solutions the system will have! But what about the det(A|B) What effect does it have! What can it show us

Comment: If $\det(A|b)\neq 0$ then the columns of $(A|b)$ are independent. This means we **cannot** express the fourth column of $(A|b)$ (i.e. the augmented part) as a linear combination of the first three columns. This means  $Ax=b$ is inconsistent.

Comment: @Matthew ok i think i got it! So what you mean is that: IFF the **det(A|b)=0** this would mean that the column vectors of the matrix **(A | b)** would be linearly dependent therefore the the column **b** could be equal to a combination of the column vectors of **A** but since the **det(A | b) is not equal to 0** this means that b cannot be equal to a linear combinations of the column vectors of **A** and therefore has no solutions at all! Did i get this right?

Comment: Yes. Very good!

Comment: @Matthew Thanks a lot m8! This helped me quite a lot!